# Chrome not playing mp4 video embedded with Flowplayer (tried diff video formats)?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, flowplayer

New to the site. Did some searching for answers to my problem, but have not found any that work. Basically, an embedded mp4 video is not playing in Chrome. Tried converting video to Webm and H26, no luck. Not sure if video format, jquery, or flowplayer are causing the issue... or all 3?

Here are snippets of the code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

---

```
<!-- flowplayer depends on jQuery 1.7.1+ (for now) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- include flowplayer -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="flowplayer.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

---

```
<div class="flowplayer no-time no-background" data-swf="flowplayer.swf" data-   key="$338652611203983" data-ratio="0.4167">
<video preload="none" muted controls>
<source type="video/mp4 src="vid/opening.mp4">
<source type="video/ogv" src="vid/openiflowplayerng.ogv">
</video>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!